# Is there a generic way to determine the URL scheme implemented by any app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

How can I know if an application is capable of being launched from another application i.e. whether or not it implements a URL scheme. And if it does, how can I know what it is?

Comment: You need to know its URL scheme first, then you can use UIApplication's canOpenURL to check if the application is installed on the device. I don't think you can find out an applications URL scheme from your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just determine any app's scheme programmatically at runtime, but if you know the specific apps you need, just ask them directly. Or check the handy (but incomplete) site ["HandleOpenURL"](http://handleopenurl.com/)